# Is there a more concise way to express this foreach loop?

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists that I need to consolidate. List 1 has only the dates, and List 2 may have the time element as well:

```
var List1 = new[] { 
  new ListType{ val = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1)}, 
  new ListType{ val = new DateTime(2012, 1, 2)} 
};

List2 = new[] { new ListType{ val = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0)} };

FinalList = new[] { 
  new ListType{ val = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0)}, 
  new ListType{ val = new DateTime(2012, 1, 2)} 
};
```

The way I'm going about this is:

```
foreach (var l in List1) {
  var match = List2.FirstOrDefault(q => q.val.Date == l.val);
  if (match == null) continue;
  l.val = match.val;
}
```

Is there a better way than iterating through List1, using FirstOrDefault and then reassigning the val?  It works, so this is just more a curiosity if Linq has a more elegant way (i.e. I am missing something obvious).

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into the Join function?

Comment: So, you are copying the time portions from `List2` into the corresponding members of `List1`?

Comment: Or even better, the Union function. In either case I would add the ("missing") values from List1 to List2 and use that instead. (I wanted to edit, but apparently this is not allowed after 5 minutes.)

Comment: [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I didn't know such a place existed.  I'll make sure to post these questions there instead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx) with a custom `IEqualityComparer<ListType>`:

```
class ListType
{
    public DateTime val { get; set; }

    public class DateComparer : IEqualityComparer<ListType>
    {
        public bool Equals(ListType x, ListType y)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
                return true;
            else if (x == null || y == null)
                return false;
            return x.val.Date == y.val.Date;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(ListType obj)
        {
            return obj.val.Date.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

and then ...

```
var finalList = List2.Union(List1, new ListType.DateComparer());
```

Comment: oh ho... That /is/ a good idea.. Thanks mate.  I knew SO would come through.

Comment: `finalList` ends up containing values for dates in `List2` which were not present in `List1`, and removes duplicates from `List1` too.

Comment: Rawling: I can deal with the minutia .. I was looking for the IEqualityComparer.  This will point me in the right direction.  In the actual solution there is more logic than just the date, but I can put that into the DateComparer class and then use that.

Comment: @Tim Well, the _question_ talks about updating an existing list of dates, setting the time part of each date to a time part taken from a different list, not about adding or removing values from that list (or creating a new list with values added or removed)... But apparently the OP was after something other than what the question asked, so meh.

Comment: @Rawling: OP has added the `FinalList` to show us what the desired result is. Since `FinalList` is != `List1` i've assumed that it's not important to modify the original list. That's why he asked if there's another way than to use the `foreach`. Btw, i wouldn't downvote competitive answers even if i'd think that mine is better.

Comment: Eh... I was reading it as if the `foreach` loop was essentially achieving what he wanted, but  I guess not.

Comment: Sorry if I was ambiguous in my question.. it /was/ early.. (:

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't get rid of the loop, but for efficiency I'd build up a dictionary mapping dates to the first matchnig time:

```
var dateToTime = List2
    .GroupBy(d => d.Date)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First());
foreach (var l in List1)
{
    DateTime match;
    if (dateToTime.TryGetValue(l.val, out match))
        l.val = match.val;
}
```

LINQ is made for querying items rather than updating items - if you need to update items, use something non-LINQ like a `foreach` loop. That said, if you want to generate a *new* list from the items in the first list, the following is the equivalent of your code:

```
var newList = List1.Select(l => new ListType { val = 
    dateToTime.ContainsKey(l.val) ? dateToTime[l.val] : l.val }).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not disagreeing that this does what I needed.  I was /looking/ for IEqualityComparer without knowing it.  There is another benefit (that I also didn't include in the question) in that I will be able to reuse the Comparer in other classes as well.